# Make already posted question community wiki

Tags: support, community-wiki

Is there is any way to convert an already posted question to community wiki? I could not find an option to do so when editing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ### How does a post become a Community Wiki post?
>
> - A moderator has reason to believe that the post serves better in community wiki mode - if you believe your post [should be converted](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/) to a community wiki, you may [flag it for moderator attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down/7183#7183).

[(Source on SE Meta)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)