# Why Can't I Make My Question Community Wiki?

Tags: discussion, questions, suggested-edits, community-wiki

I was looking around the part where you can ask a question in my accounts and I was wondering how do you make the questions community wiki. One example of an community wiki question was asked by the ***AWESOME*** Jon Skeet: [What's your most controversial programming opinion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406760/whats-your-most-controversial-programming-opinion)
There was no checkbox for making the post community wiki like the ones for answers. I have tried using the tag `community-wiki` on one of my questions and it obviously didn't work. So how exactly do you make a *question* a community wiki question?

Comment: You can't.  If you want it, flag it.  [Make already posted question community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278715/make-already-posted-question-community-wiki)

Comment: Note that the question you are using as an example is off-topic on Stack Overflow by today’s definition.

Comment: I know but my reason for using it is that it is a community wiki question.

Comment: It is historically locked because by today's standards it is *awful*. It should be deleted with zeal, but some merciful mod locked it so you can read and gawk at what it was like in the early days of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ability to make questions community wiki from the start was removed since it was a confusing feature and often misused. And even now, there are not many good use cases left where a community wiki question is deemed useful or on-topic. That being said, if you truly think your question is a good question that should be made community wiki, you can [ask a moderator by flagging the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278715/make-already-posted-question-community-wiki).

To learn more about when and why the community wiki feature was removed from question, see [this post on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better).