# I flagged my question to make it a community wiki, and the flag apparently does not "require their intervention"

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, declined-flags, community-wiki

I flagged [a question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71664714/215552) with a moderator flag, following the advice in [Make already posted question community wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278715/make-already-posted-question-community-wiki). I used the text:

> I'd like to make this question a community wiki as I seem to be unable to do it myself and was unable to do so through the wizard.

Since I was forced through the Ask a Question Wizard, [I couldn't self-answer immediately](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/416792/215552) and from [the source for the answer to the previous post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts), the community wiki checkbox was removed anyway.

It was declined with the message:

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

Perhaps I worded the request poorly or otherwise messed something up, but I'm not sure what other avenue I have to make an already-posted question a community wiki.

Comment: *"A moderator has reason to believe that the post serves better in community wiki mode"* - The _moderator_ has reason to believe that it's better as a community wiki, not the user. I decline reason was poor, "no evidence" would've been better IMO, but a decline isn't _totally_ unreasonable given the guidance you link to.

Comment: Tangentially, I don't think you could have chosen to make the **question** a community wiki even if you didn't go through the wizard. One can only mark an **answer** as a wiki when posting it, right?

Comment: This has been resolved.

Comment: @yivi I was a little confused. We used to have a checkbox where we could make a *question* a community wiki when asking. It was removed some time ago, apparently. I don't really ask questions, as I generally find answers to my questions through research.

Comment: It is a bit unfortunate that the question is now locked from voting. An upvotes question would be easier to find for future users

Comment: I saw close votes, so I locked it. Should I just close/reopen it?

Comment: You've never been able to mark your own question as CW, at least not for a very long while.

Comment: On an unrelated note: while it's perfectly fine (in fact, encouraged!) to create canonical FAQ-style questions, we do at least require that you ask them in the form of a question (the whole "pretend you're on Jeopardy!" thing). What you posted really doesn't meet my minimum expectations for an SO question, whether CW or not. If you're really just trying to create an index, with no other content, that probably belongs in the [[tag:c#]] tag wiki instead of in a Q&A.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz explain to me how votes affect searching?

Comment: @Braiam It affects finding in the sense that users might be more inclined to click on a search result which has a couple of votes. No idea if search engines also might take the sore into account.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz that's the thing, no (common) search engine shows you the score on the question. You are presented just with the title and maybe a excerpt of the text of the question.

Comment: @Braiam The on-site search shows the score

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz how many people use on-site search? [Less than .7%](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/03/09/anyone-actually-visit-stack-overflows-home-page/) of all hits. Registered users 1.1% and unregistered less than .4%. So, your argument doesn't hold water, as 99.9% of all users don't use on-site search.

Answer (score -2):

Let’s ignore the how to make a question community wiki for a little while focusing on one more important aspect: that is not a question. Yes, it was posted on the question box, posttypeid is indeed 2, but it's not a question.

Self-answered questions, community wiki question and regular questions need to follow all the rules: they should be actual questions. That post doesn't clear the modicum requirements for it, and even if worded as a question (as the title does) it is not clear and not specific to have a focused, concrete, useful answer.

That post, and what it attempts, does not belong to the Q&A format and will never be. And before the "but let’s use it as duplication target" you are missing the point of duplication closure: making easier to the future reader to find the answers to their questions. Throwing them to another wall of text that they have to parse instead of intermediately get the answer they are looking for, will only motivate them to ask it anyway.

That's why, despite the PHP version existing for years, PHP guys still get [these kind of questions regularly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71321243/792066) (to not fault the asker entirely either because search engines suck for symbols).

This question will not solve the problem it purposes to solve, because the problem is not that our content is unfindable; it's that the most common tool to find what you are looking for should not be used to find what these users are trying to find.

Comment: "Let's ignore the meta question and talk about a different topic". Nah, let's not. If you'd like to discuss the topicality of the main question, ask a new meta question.

Comment: Or join [the chat created from the comments on the post, which makes many of the same arguments you make here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243426/discussion-on-question-by-heretic-monkey-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-c)