# Should I really not try to make artificial "signpost duplicates"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions, signpost-questions

Today I attempted this project: [Why did I get a "SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72495496/)

I am an [SME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject-matter_expert), so of course I do not have such a problem myself. There are [over a hundred](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22can%27t%20assign%20to%20function%20call%22%20%5bpython%5d%20is%3aquestion) questions on Stack Overflow with a common proximate cause (trying to assign to the result of a function call, like the error message says).

Many of these questions can be categorized as typos, but it will often be the case that OP is too unskilled to recognize the typo or understand why the syntax is invalid. Even when it is clearly a typo, it is [faster to dupehammer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319399/closing-questions-with-typos-faster-typo-hammer) when a canonical duplicate is available, and apparently many people in the past did find such questions worthy of answers.

The problem for dupe-voters is that there is a **wide** variety of *ultimate* causes for the error: i.e. what OP was trying to accomplish. Each of these necessarily indicates a different explanation, because "don't write it like that" isn't helpful; the OP needs to figure out what *should* be written instead. However, these questions tend to have very non-descriptive titles. It's really, really hard to give them titles that make it obvious which ultimate cause is discussed; and even if this were somehow attempted, the search results would still be awful.

---

My thought was to gather the various questions, do a little cleanup, identify *patterns* in how people end up writing the code wrongly, and categorize them by ultimate cause.

For each cause, I could pick the best target, dupe-hammer the others, and then *provide a listing* that others could use as a reference to get the right canonicals (instead of having to *read* through dozens of questions that came up in the search box). For example, I noticed that a large number of these questions are *really* duplicates of [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/) or similar; these ones are best addressed by ignoring the question about the `SyntaxError` and directly engaging with OP's ill-conceived goal.

To make the question and answer separately useful, I ask some general questions about the error, as a framing device:

> The error message in these cases is pretty self-explanatory: the code tries to assign to "a function call", and this is not allowed. But what does that actually mean? What can we assign to, and why is syntax like `foo() = 3` not valid? How can I figure out the right code to do what I want, depending on what the context (the actual `foo` function)?

For each cause, I give a brief summary (since the original Q&A pairs often have difficulty getting to the point, even after editing); I also try to answer the conceptual question about why such code is erroneous.

---

This effort does not appear to have been well received, or at least it is controversial. Have I done something wrong? How can I improve the question and answer? I had recently seen [an excellent artificial duplicate by Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/) on a different topic. I have a different problem to solve, but I had inferred that there is a fair bit of leeway on Stack Overflow when it comes to asking questions "artificially".

Comment: [Jon's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72495496/what-does-syntaxerror-cannot-assign-to-function-call-mean-how-can-i-assign-t#comment128065037_72495496) answers  your question here, really. Your question ain't a question; _all_ questions (no exceptions) have to be actual questions, not an explanation for its existence. Peter Cordes' canonical is a question, and a high-quality one at that. Not gonna comment on the answer because I didn't read that far and I don't really need to. A high-quality answer is arguably useless without a good question

Comment: You really don't need the first 3 paragraphs. They have nothing to do with the question on main. Here's another example of an "artificial signpost" [How do I calculate square root in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70793490/15497888) where the question is the focus, and the related commentary is _much_ less highlighted.

Comment: The problem is that if I make a 'related" section like that, then the titles will be hard to interpret. Also, how are people supposed to understand the purpose and treat the question properly (rather than as if I sincerely had the question) if I don't explain? It seems like at least one person misunderstood (and offered me a dupe link) even though I *did* explain. Peter's question starts off with several paragraphs of answering before anything that so much as hints at a question mark.

Comment: I tried to rearrange things by moving the requests for help to comments on the answer, and putting the explanation below the actual question in the question. I hope this is a significant improvement.

Comment: "_Even when it is clearly a typo, it is faster to dupehammer_"--That does not necessarily mean that it _should_ be dupehammered, if it is actually a typo.

Comment: @khelwood I included the link specifically because I would rather not rehash that argument myself.

Comment: I don't think you _need_ a related section; I wasn't suggesting you model your question exactly after the one I linked. My point is that the actual _question_ is currently taking up less than a quarter of the question text. This as compared to a different attempt where the question is first and foremost. Additionally, whether a question is opened or closed doesn't matter all that much as it can be used as a duplicate target either way.

Comment: I tried to fix the problems, but people only seem to think it's worse. I don't care about it being closed; the problem is that the proposed duplicate is inappropriate. It highlights one of the many possible options for no good reason. Even if I had actually had the problem described, the correct duplicate could have been one of a dozen other questions. Which *is exactly why I'm doing this*!

Comment: Something of a pedantic point, but you seem to be talking about creating a _canonical_ rather than a signpost - a duplicate of a canonical that matches popular search terms that the canonical doesn't, allowing searchers to be find the answers that they're seeking.

Comment: @snakecharmerb My intent is not for the question I made to be used as a dupe target, but to contain links for other dupe targets. The point is that it's hard to find the right one normally, and this makes it easier.

Comment: Your question is phrased poorly, is unclear, and seems to rely on the question title to do the heavy-lifting of asking the question, where the important information about hte problem/question is missing from the body. Even when creating an artificial question, you should at least ask a good question.

Comment: The question **has to** be unclear, because it **has to** lack a MRE, because any possible MRE would *require choosing one of the specific contexts* in which the error occurs, and the *entire point* of the question is to collect those contexts together (with the possible contexts in the answer) *so that close-voters can find the right one more easily*. Are you suggesting that I should instead give multiple trivial MREs for each possible context, in the question? Because I could do that, but I can't get my head around how I would write the surrounding text.

Comment: You know, I really have come to hate this. I go out of my way to try to create something useful for the community, and also come to meta to talk about it, and it seems like everyone gives statements about how it's bad but is neither willing to improve it (despite my explicit invitation) nor give concrete advice on doing so. Over and over people say things that indicate that they don't understand an intent that I explained repeatedly, as clearly as I know how.

Comment: I think adding a few common examples to the question could help, even as is it's kind of hard to see what the actual question is. The content in the title (the error message) should probably also be repeated and emphasized in the question so someone who finds it can understand how it might relate to their specific problem - e.g. "when I run this code, I get this error. How do I fix it?". FWIW I like [this template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value) for a canonical you know the answer to.

Comment: Asking a general question is not the same as trying to ask an unclear and unfocused question. Your question is unclear because the actual problem is missing from the body of the question. Your question is unfocused, because it asks three or four sweeping questions that are already broad on their own, let alone when combined. The fact that your note is larger than your question itself is also indicative of the problem, IMHO.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Do you understand the intended purpose of the question? Can you explicitly suggest a change in wording, or better yet make your own edit? Why isn't anyone apparently willing to help out here, but only criticize the existing effort, when I have gone out of my way to explain that this is intended to be a collaborative effort intended to make life easier for a community of SMEs going forward?

Comment: Please keep in mind that for some of the possible causes listed, it really isn't possible to give more useful context than the `foo() = 3` example. In one of the cases I turned up while searching, OP *legitimately believed that it should be possible to include parentheses in an identifier name*. I do think this is something that could plausibly happen again. I do think it would not qualify as a typo. I do think it would be unreasonably difficult to find the duplicate, without the kind of guidance I am offering here.

Comment: At minimum you should repeat the title - or at least the error - in the body (maybe phrased differently). You also need to focus on one question only. The fact you're trying to create a signpost question doesn't absolve you from the normal requirements for asking questions.

Comment: The entire point of the signpost is to know which way to go. I can't make multiple signposts, because either they would all have the same title, or they would all be too long to fit. The search results are already crowded with stuff that will mostly be irrelevant, and the search is poor. I want to make something bookmarkable for reference.

Comment: Possibly also related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252868

Comment: Because of the initial bad phrasing the question end up getting a bad score. Might be hard to get out of it though.

Comment: I only care about the question score insofar as it affects visibility. There are relatively few gold-badge Python users; if all of them know the question exists, I have achieved my goal already.

Comment: Maybe there's something I'm not seeing, but if there's controversy over whether such a resource properly constitutes a Stack overflow question, why not just post (a version of) it in Meta instead? Meta's rules are much more flexible in general, and it's still easily accessible and editable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I made the answer a community wiki, and [flagged the question to request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278715) the same. Thank you to Dharman for granting the request.

If there are any further changes to make, I welcome everyone with community wiki privileges to make them. I have no interest in reputation points for any of this; I am explicitly trying to offer a service to regulars in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) to make their lives easier.

I also attempted my own improvements, partially based on comment feedback, categorized thus:

### The question should not drown in meta commentary

- I moved the paragraphs commenting on duplicate quality, and asking for help, to comments on the answer.
- I switched the remaining paragraphs in the question, so that the explicitly asked questions are on top, and the explanation of the meta purpose on bottom. I added emphasis to the questions to make sure it is clear what questions are being asked.
- Subsequently, however, I decided to rewrite the question, following an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766) highlighted by Tyler V. Following that template, the "disclaimer" portion is up top again, but the substance of the question takes up a much larger fraction of the post.

I realize now that Peter Cordes' canonical is a poor model for my question: the ASM question answers a "what will happen?" in detail, but puts the answer (without asking) for "what should I do?" up front. That makes sense there because a) there is a clear answer for "what should I do?", and b) *most beginners should not worry about* "what will happen?", since "what should I do?" involves taking a different approach entirely. In my case, the *entire point* is that "what should I do?" *greatly varies*, while "what will happen?" *has already happened*.

### Even though the context varies, show the common code

- I gave several examples of possible syntax that reproduces the error, even though the *semantic/ultimate* cause of the error depends on a widely varying context. After all, that context is not actually required to reproduce the error; it's only relevant to to the "what should I do?" question. I realized that even though I primarily intend for the question to be bookmarked by dupe-hammer-wielders, it could also be found by a search engine, and *I should improve the experience* for anyone who does. Code examples do that, by making the question more relatable.
- Code examples have a certain amount of memorability to them. I edited the `foo() = 3` bit into the title, because that makes it easier to search for the signpost. I decided that the title does not really need anything outside of joining that example to the error message - so as not to provoke "too broad" reflexes.

---

Because the question is currently closed, I cannot post new answers. If I could, I would probably move the Pandas-related links to a separate answer, for the sake of sorting through them in isolation. It's possible that a good, separate signpost duplicate could be made from them. It's even conceivable (I am not a Pandas SME) that a *canonical* could be made, explaining a general technique for assigning to cells selected by Pandas functionality.

Comment: I don't really understand why the "Self-answered questions still need to be questions" comment on the question continued getting more upvotes after my edit. I ran out of ways to make the existence of the question more obvious.

Comment: I think the edited version is much more clear about the question. I am still not sure about the premise that the question itself should not be a dupe target. Each question and it's answers should be a standalone resource, which is why link-only answers aren't allowed. If the question and its answers adequately explain the problem and how to fix it why wouldn't it work like any other general/canonical question?

Comment: @TylerV because it isn't *specific*. There might be a rare occasion where someone genuinely wonders about the error message in general, and can be directed there. But in the normal case, someone will have written code that matches the code pattern, and the code will be incorrect for *exactly one* of the candidate reasons suggested. The close-voters will naturally be more qualified than OP to figure out which one.

Comment: In general someone would search the error message itself, not knowing the cause. Having a list of possible causes in an answer would let them find the specific cause for their occurrence of that error. Sort of like the java NullPointerException canonical - too many possible scenarios can lead to it to list all possibilities so instead you provide more general information the asker can apply to their problem

Answer (score 3):

Above all, the question should not look like a fabrication or fake scenario simply setting up the answer. Instead, the question should be one that you'd typically find in the wild... if not actually *being* a question found in the wild that you or the community improved/answered.

Effectively... even though you're trying to provide a service to the community by producing a high-quality Q/A pair... it should still at minimum actually contain a question someone might reasonably have. Otherwise... you might end up in a scenario where the question is actually too broad, and by trying to help all the different ways a particular problem can manifest in one swing you end up providing subpar assistance for all of them. It should be easy for an asker to, from your question, recognize that it's relevant to them, and from there quickly find the answer below without having to figure out which solution in your answer applies to them. An explanation that it's a dupe target, canonical, self answered, etc. is noise and likely to attract negative attention.

Comment: I solicited this answer as a follow-up to chat in the Meta room. During that discussion, we determined that the first link in my answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964927, is itself suitable as a canonical for several (though probably not all) possible underlying causes of the error - even though OP of course only experienced one of them. (It is not actually certain which one, although answers from the time all made the same guess).

Comment: On Jul 4 a new community wiki answer appeared there, and my intent is to expand that answer, hammer what is appropriate, and eventually trash or hammer the original "signpost" QA pair that prompted this meta question. Unfortunately, this seems to just shift the burden of "figuring out which solution applies" to the asker - but the burden really seems unavoidable and it has to go somewhere. Mjollnir-wielders can be considerate by leaving a short comment along with the duplicate closure, I guess.

Answer (score -1):

I recently read [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363030/are-faq-tags-good?noredirect=1&lq=1) which asked about [*-faq] tags.

Yakk - Adam Nevraumont's [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/363049/6632744) explains the [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) tag, and how it's currently well maintained and not abused.

It seems like there are a few [*-faq] tags out there, and they're a solution which is currently accepted by the community as a solution to the problem of trying to identify good dupe targets.

I also think it's a good idea to read over [the post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252874/setting-up-a-faq-for-the-c-tag) which sets up the [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) tag. The question contains some good arguments for it, and there's an answer which contains good arguments against. One thing that came up in that discussion was the fact that expert users were creating contrived questions in order to post the answers they wanted. While this was something that might seem useful to an expert, the messy reality is that programmers who don't understand what "cannot assign to function call" means aren't likely to understand how to manipulate general advice about the error to their own situation.

Personally, I think establishing a [python-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-faq) tag would be useful. I'm not particularly active in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) though, and perhaps our active Python experts would disagree. If there is an active enough community of people who share an enthusiasm for creating and maintaining such a tag, perhaps a list of high-quality real world questions could be collated to serve as canonical dupe targets for the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) community.

Comment: Note there's https://sopython.com/canon/

Comment: I had previously posted on that question. I got the impression that first off trying to open up `[python-faq]` would get lukewarm reception at best. While looking over the "cannot assign to function call" search results, I realized that simply adding them to a list would not provide adequate guidance, especially if it were a general Python FAQ list. The question isn't meant for beginners to be referred to; it's *primarily* meant to help dupe-hammer-wielders find the best target.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The canon is a good idea, but it's off-site and I can't just submit content for it whenever I like. It's also much too sparse for what it's trying to do. If I could, I'd add something like my answer to the canon - but it would stand out as vastly more detailed than anything else.

Comment: I assume from the downvotes on my answer, the [python-faq] idea isn't a well supported one. It looks like [c++-faq] is primarily a dupe-hammer target list. It's not really meant to be somewhere that new users are pointed to.

Comment: I don't understand the distinction you are trying to draw here. We don't specifically "point new users at" material, aside from closing their questions as duplicates of those targets, because this isn't a discussion forum. Of course a FAQ tag will behave as a dupe-hammer target list, because the entire site is a collaborative FAQ-writing exercise, and any question that can be answered by the existing FAQ contents is by definition a duplicate. *Neither is my question intended to be the direct duplicate target*.

Comment: Both my Q&A pair, and the `[c++-faq]` tag, are unconventional techniques working within the available tech, to *make it easier for dupe-markers to find the right duplicates*. Neither of them is intended for *any other* purpose. I keep saying that over and over and nobody seems to get it. Any concessions I make to other potential purposes are simply because everyone is insisting on not bending the rules.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel But how to "find the right duplicates" or what is a good duplicate or duplicate list are not good SO questions & not something people who want an answer to should expect to find on SO. So people keep suggesting ways to get an on-topic Q&A for your goals. If you want to get people duplicates there's no reason you or they would use SO just because they are SO posts being linked to by SO posts.

Comment: "If you want to get people duplicates there's no reason you or they would use SO just because" Have you ever *tried* using the SOPython canon in a separate tab while trying to close a question? It's an admirable effort, but it's very unsupported. I don't see any way I personally can contribute to it, and certainly not with the wiki-like ease of the main site. But even if its content were perfect, it would still be clunky UI-wise just because it's a separate website in a separate tab.