# Is writing a guide instead of a question allowed?

Tags: discussion, questions

I came across this post:

[Guide: How to store objects in a Hive database in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76410407/guide-how-to-store-objects-in-a-hive-database-in-flutter)

This post doesn't pose a question but rather instead, provides a guide on how to accomplish a specific task.

From what I understand, Stack Overflow is a **Q&A** site, and not intended for the above-styled posts.

---

On the other hand, I did come across a few posts for canonicals such as:

[I'm getting a TypeError. How do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73631401/im-getting-a-typeerror-how-do-i-fix-it)

which seems to be allowed.

**So, Are writing guides as a post allowed?**

Comment: No, that sort of "guide" needs to either be posted as an Article in a Collective, or as an answer to a question (which one could also write themself).  Note that the TypeError canonical poses a question that it then answers.

Comment: Rather than writing the guide as a **question**, the poster should write some simple question *How to store objects in a Hive database in Flutter* then add a **[self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)** with the contents of the guide.  Questions with self-answers are explicitly encouraged, I've written a few myself.

Comment: The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76410407/guide-how-to-store-objects-in-a-hive-database-in-flutter) is deleted by the author. Do you guys can see the question?

Comment: @Adamu_Dee_Azare Yes; seeing deleted questions comes at 10k rep.

Comment: I would already argue that it might not even be a valid answer when posted as an answer. If a question requires a full guide to answer it, that question might be a tad on the broad side. It shouldn't be necessary to have the book thrown at you by someone else when you can read the book yourself.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

No.

As you emphasized yourself - Stack Overflow's core is being a ***Q & A*** site. A repository of high-quality programming-related questions and their answers given by other users according to their level of expertise. Those answers can then be rated so other users can have a clear view about the community's consensus regarding the correctness and/or quality of the answers.

Posting such *"guide"* breaks this basic principle. Apart from the fact that it's still possible to vote on this *"guide"* (to show maybe if it's good/correct or not), there is nothing to answer and a major participation aspect of the community is taken away.

It is, however, accepted and completely fine to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). So if someone really wanted to post such *"guide"*, it could be possible to formulate a question about a problem which the *"guide"* aims to solve, and post the *"guide"* as a self-answer to it. It is important to make sure that such question doesn't already exist.
If it doesn't and you are going to post one, ***make sure your question is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [suitable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for this site*** and that it follows the [standard guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for writing questions.

---

Regarding the second example you brought - notice that it follows this guideline. It was [posted with a self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73631401/timeline#history_7a598f24-1462-41b8-8940-b51319cd52fb) and although it was made *"artificially"* (was written to the sole purpose of being answered), it was formulated as a standard question as if someone encountered the error and asking how to solve it.

Comment: Yup. It's important to notice the emphasis in this answer. It's fine to answer your own question, but **it must be a good question**. I've written a few self-answered questions over the years, and the best result is often when someone with more expertise provides an even better or more complete answer. So ask as if you are actually asking! Provide an answer if you can, but don't post a self-answer as if it's the final word on the subject. If only you can answer the question, then it's a really bad question.

Comment: As the author of the artificial question... in question: [see also](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418516/) a time that I attempted this and it *didn't* go very well.

Answer (score 2):

Guides are rarely directly good answers. They're never good questions (for they are not questions at all).

If the guide is a general explanation of a tag, the tag wiki page is an appropriate place for it.

Otherwise, write the guide elsewhere and link to it from here in appropriate places, probably with relevant quote (especially when used in an answer).

Comment: 1 - Many people, unless they own (and pay for hosting or self-host) a personal domain don't have a good place to put a guide elsewhere; 2 - a guide can significantly benefit from the collaborative editing/"answering" provided by existing SE Q&A tools - none of that will work if someone posts a link to their external post; 3 - tag wikis are not easily found and not comprehensive enough (size, formatting, etc.) for this purpose

Comment: "Many people, unless they own (and pay for hosting or self-host) a personal domain don't have a good place to put a guide elsewhere" - sign up for a free GitHub account; follow instructions to set up a blog served from that account; write the guide as a blog article, using Markdown. That's what I do. Alternately, use Wordpress etc. There are many free options.

Answer (score -3):

This is an extremely common problem. On [Home Improvement Stack Exchange](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) we get a ton of questions that could be answered with comprehensive guides on specific topics. In fact, we tried doing that a while back with a guide on some basic electrical work. **I can't even find it now!** The idea was to have something more than just a duplicate as a Close target, because the  "Close" and "Duplicate" concepts are extremely confusing for new users, and this would provide a step-by-step guide to a series of common issues.

But there was no practical way to do it. If a post isn't updated frequently it drops off the recent list and is hard to find when you want it, unless you save a link to it somewhere.

As my username shows, I have been working with a new system, [Codidact](https://codidact.org/) and this is one of the things we have added there. Codidact doesn't have the number of users and posts that Stack Exchange has (nothing does!), but the point is that this type of thing ("guide", "canonical post", "article", whatever you want to call it) can be integrated into a Q&A system if the makers of the system really want to do so.

I am **not** suggesting everyone (or anyone, for that matter) should jump to Codidact. I am pointing out that there are ways to build a *primarily* Q&A system to allow for "guide" answers.