# Why is this FAQ getting downvoted, and how can I improve it?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have recently made a new [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) question [What is the precedence and associativity of operators, and how are these rules defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77168306/5740428) and put a few hours of work into compiling it all.

For some reason, the question keeps getting downvoted. I have initially made an FAQ for both C and C++, but I have deleted it because too many people found the decision to combine the languages controversial. That one was also getting heavily downvoted, and I was under the impression that it's just because of this language mixing issue, but people seem to dislike the question itself no matter whether it's language-specific or not.

I have designed my FAQ in the style of [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/5740428), which has been very well received and is similarly structured.

Is there something obvious I am missing here? What could I improve about this FAQ so that people don't reject it?

Comment: Why does something that's very well documented need an FAQ on SO?

Comment: @Cerbrus because it keeps the information on-site and lets you use the FAQ as a duplicate that can be linked to. There are countless questions which ask about a specific operator precedence issue but there isn't a good duplication target for them. Also you could make the argument that the operator overloading FAQ has no right to exist because operator overloading is very well documented on cppreference. That isn't community consensus though, seeing thousands of upvotes.

Comment: Also, using a question that's 13 years old is not a very good justification... Rules change, what was a good question then, may not be one, now.

Comment: The operator overloading FAQ has gotten 4 downvotes in 13 years so there is no reason to believe that consensus has shifted against such FAQs being useful. If people disliked FAQs now, they would downvote them. They do downvote mine, and there is presumably an issue with it, but I don't think it's because people generally find FAQs useless.

Comment: I think most people know that things have changed in the last 13 years and don't downvote old questions.

Comment: What has changed? There always used to be off-site information that you could link to, and that didn't stop people from making FAQs on SO.

Comment: The downvote arrow has a very clear title: _"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"_

Comment: @Cerbrus do you believe my question/FAQ has not shown any research effort and is unclear/not useful? If so, why?

Comment: I already answered that: _"Why does something that's very well documented need an FAQ on SO?"_ It's not useful.

Comment: That is such a non-answer. Everything is already documented somewhere else. C++ is entirely documented in the C++ standard and on cppreference and you could just burninate [c++] if you go by that standard. Why do we need Stack Overflow then? Why do we need any FAQ then?

Comment: The question _"For example, is 1 + 2 * 2 equal to 6, or equal to 5?"_ doesn't show any research effort. It can be answered with a basic program or quick research.

Comment: @jabaa it's just an introductory sentence so that there is something that all answers in the FAQ can refer to. There's obviously more to the question, and it's apparent that it's in an FAQ format. https://stackoverflow.com/q/57483/5740428 has also not shown research effort and has almost 4000 upvotes.

Comment: Also, operator precedence is just __basic math.__ It's the first thing you learn when you start doing sums with more than one operator...

Comment: If a question can be answered by the first result of your search engine, it's lacking research. The same with _"What is the precedence and associativity of operators in C++?"_ Type this into your search engine instead of asking this question.

Comment: IMO, [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) should also be applied to FAQ questions.

Comment: @jabaa there are countless questions that simply ask "What is X" and have thousands of upvotes, or even tens of thousands. A good question only has to show enough research effort to be useful and well answerable. All I could do is fill the question with content which belongs in an answer. Ultimately, this has nothing to do with the quality of the FAQ as a whole, it's just a shift in content from one place to the other. Arguably, this makes the FAQ worse because the question becomes needlessly verbose.

Comment: A question that's answered by the first result of your search engine is not useful: _"Asking a question on Stack Overflow should be the last step in your process for finding an answer—if the information that you need already exists, then you should be able to find it before asking.

You want to

    Search. Like mad.
    Test your code.
    Troubleshoot.
    Read blogs.
    Find books.
    Follow tutorials.
"_

Comment: @jabaa how come [What does the explicit keyword mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/121162/5740428) has close to 4000 upvotes then? It shows no research effort and can also be answered with the first result from cppreference or whatever Google brought up back in the day.

Comment: That's a question from ___2008___. Times change, rules change. If that were posted now, it'd get closed and deleted in an _instant_.

Comment: It's 15 years old. Maybe then the research effort wasn't expected. Today it is expected.

Comment: @jabaa it's only gotten a dozen or so downvotes in 15 years. Once again, even if the standards of the community change and a question violates site policy over time, you would think that it would get downvotes eventually or that it would get a historical lock. I don't buy the explanation that 100% of users looks at the age of the question and decides to apply a different standard of quality either.

Comment: Again: Most users know that rules have changed and don't downvote old questions.

Comment: Or maybe most people just understand that we don't necessarily need to shackle grandpa. He's harmless, even though he's not exactly "with it" in current times.

Comment: @jabaa keep the numbers in mind. It has gotten less than one downvote a year despite being of low quality by modern standards. I don't buy the explanation that 100% of users keeps the age in mind.

Comment: You don't need to buy it. You found old questions that were upvoted and similar new questions that are downvoted.

Comment: Mate, if your best defence is a ___15-year-old___ question, you're going to need to reconsider you may be wrong. Questions _that old_ are basically irrelevant when policy is concerned.

Comment: It's not about site policy, it's about voting patterns. You keep missing the point. This whole meta question is about voting patterns.

Comment: _"How can I improve this?" "You can't, it's not a good fit for SO"_.

Comment: Alright, you're entitled to your opinion. Personally I disagree, and it would be good to have some rationale for such a claim.

Comment: I don't like questions that are placeholders rather than real questions. If there is a question, ask it. If not, consider improving already existing ones. If a question doesn't have a good dupe, answer that question and use that question as a dupe in the future. Generating new questions just to summarize already existing ones looks like a bad practice - without a mechanism to "canonize" such questions they just increase entropy and hide other, sometimes really good, answers.

Comment: @Evg I've wanted to do that but I was unable to find any such existing more-or-less canonical Q&A where I could post about operator precedence. I could only find specific questions with mostly low votes, and those wouldn't be good targets.

Comment: I would be grateful if you could provide a good target question where I could post my FAQ answers, if one exists.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39126127/operator-precedence-and-evaluation-order#:~:text=Operator%20precedence%20only%20determines%20that,y)%20%26%26%20(%2B%2Bz)%20. That wasn't exactly hard to google.

Comment: But maybe the fact that no "Operator precedence" canonical exists, if because it's _very well documented_ elsewhere.

Comment: @Cerbrus that questions is arguably too narrow because it's highly focused on logical operators, and it also confuses evaluation order which isn't really the subject of the FAQ. It's also a duplicate.

Comment: For example, your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77168307 could've gone here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20767745.

Comment: @Evg that already has a better answer with the same (plagiarized) grammar block ;-)

Comment: @Evg that half, yeah, I agree. It's arguably the less interesting half because most people are just interested in what the precedence is, not how the precedence emerges from the grammar.

Comment: @Cerbrus Exactly. That's my point - the new question doesn't add anything to existing ones (except `c++-faq` tag).

Comment: @Evg the idea was that there are countless questions in the style of "What gets executed first in `*ptr++` etc. and I wanted to created a canonical dupe target/useful link. It could have been a useful site-internal link to hundreds or thousands of questions. That's why I don't agree with "this has no use".

Comment: @Cerbrus it's not plagiarized just because it contains a few lines of grammar rule from the C++ standard. Are you saying that Joseph's answer is plagiarism because it doesn't link to the standard?

Comment: The problem is that this canonical dupe won't become a canonical dupe in practice. Those who research most likely will find an answer themselves, those who prefer to ask without research will open a new question anyway, those who close questions as dupes might not know about your question at all. SO doesn't provide a good practical mechanism to support canonical dupes. I understand and agree with your intention, but unfortunately it's not practical at SO.

Comment: It's easy to say that it won't become a canonical dupe target now that it's been downvoted to pieces. I think there would have been a chance though if it just took off and people didn't do that. You're right that there isn't any practical mechanism though; you just have to pray, or you have to be one of the lucky few who got thousands of upvotes for asking "What is NULL?" or something.

Comment: Nowadays, canonical dupes could emerge from really good questions and even more better answers because they are really really good, not because they are termed canonical by more or less random choice.

Comment: @Evg I took your advice and posted an explanation of precedence and evaluation order at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20767745. It's still unfortunate that we don't have a canonical for an operator precedence table, given how often that question pops up on this site. I also doubt that a suggestion to add that feature would go anywhere tbh.

Comment: Just as a reference, I once wrote a very similar self-answered Q&A for C.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369090/operator-precedence-table-for-the-c-programming-language. 

Notably this was written at a point when C11 was still new and cppreference.com contained questionable information, so it was _not_ well-documented elsewhere at the time. Still I'm not sure if this was such a good idea.

Comment: The correct place to put this documentation is probably in the C and C++ standards respectively. Although I'm not sure what SO can do to make the C and C++ working groups to recognize that their documents needed fixing as per the first pre-ANSI drafts around 1989...

Comment: Precedence tables is just a phenomenon created due to a dysfunctional standard failing to provide a readable overview of its own syntax. In fact precedence tables originate from the K&R book and pre-dates ISO C standardization by at least 10 years. So when they wrote the first standard they must have thought that having a completely muddy slop chapter (6.5) would be acceptable because we can always look it up in K&R, right? Well, we can't since K&R was always even more sloppy than the standard, not even bothering to separate prefix and postfix operators - their table is just an embarrassment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Framing the question

I want to highlight a few points from the comments that I think exemplify the key disagreements here.

As a general observation, I do strongly feel *in general* that a Q&A site should be able to host content like this. Stack Overflow isn't especially well designed for it, unfortunately. The Software section on Codidact might add more "categories" besides the main Q&A (and "code reviews") in the future, which might make it easier - there's a lot to discuss still. But it's not a good idea to rely on the fact of other sites being able to provide answers for basic research questions. Sometimes they're all just bad at presentation (more on that later).

More importantly, Stack Overflow has enough problems keeping itself DRY without trying to keep the rest of the Internet DRY. If many people are asking about the same basic research topic, having a local answer that can be used as a duplicate is clearly more expedient, and it builds the perception of the community actually being a **place that builds and presents expertise**.

This is my warning to those of you who wish for Stack Overflow to remain dominant in its niche: if you *don't* see the value in this, don't be surprised when other sites that do, eventually overtake you. (I think they will anyway, but "eventually" can be longer or shorter.)

#### [Dorothy Dix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dorothy_Dixer)'s mental acuity

> The question *"For example, is 1 + 2 * 2 equal to 6, or equal to 5?"* doesn't show any research effort. It can be answered with a basic program or quick research.

Of course, I understand that this is intended as a framing question. But there are at least two problems here:

1. "What is the result of this code?" questions would be closed with the reasoning that there is no substance; they are answered by *trying* the code, and we don't provide that service. In reality, beginner-level questions about operator precedence are going to come out of a **debugging effort**.
2. While it's important for examples to be simple, they should at least be **realistic**. I've seen that a fair number of people learn or remember their grade-school arithmetic incorrectly, in particular, by thinking that *each letter* in BEDMAS (or PEMDAS, depending on locale) represents a separate "pass" (rather than recognizing that multiplication and division should have the same precedence, or addition and subtraction likewise).

#### Appreciating the scale of the problem

> Also, operator precedence is just basic math. It's the first thing you learn when you start doing sums with more than one operator...

Just a small observation in passing, which I think helps tie the other two points together. I consider myself lucky to have received an excellent computer science education, but it wasn't in my math classroom. Aside from "wait, the computer (really, the design of the programming language, but we'll let that slide) actually cares about order of operations?" is **actually not obvious**; popular languages *could* all have been designed *not* to. It's not as if expressions in code actually look the way they do in a math classroom (although I'm sure someone out there is working on an esolang that involves typing in LaTeX for simple expressions and having an editor render it on the fly). And aside from all of that, I *certainly* have not seen any grade-school math classrooms discuss `>>` and `<<`, let alone their precedence.

And all of that is without even considering the idea of *operator overloads for non-numeric types* (including the ones built in to the language or standard library).

#### About research and documentation

> If a question can be answered by the first result of your search engine, it's lacking research. The same with "What is the precedence and associativity of operators in C++?" Type this into your search engine instead of asking this question.

Okay; I [tried exactly that](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=What+is+the+precedence+and+associativity+of+operators+in+C%2B%2B%3F).

Most of the results are overly dry presentations of the actual facts, as described in that title. For example, Wikipedia tells us

> The following is a table that lists the precedence and associativity of all the operators in the C and C++ languages. Operators are listed top to bottom, in descending precedence. Descending precedence refers to the priority of the grouping of operators and operands. Considering an expression, an operator which is listed on some row will be grouped prior to any operator that is listed on a row further below it. Operators that are in the same cell (there may be several rows of operators listed in a cell) are grouped with the same precedence, in the given direction. An operator's precedence is unaffected by overloading.

> The syntax of expressions in C and C++ is specified by a phrase structure grammar.[6] The table given here has been inferred from the grammar.[citation needed] For the ISO C 1999 standard, section 6.5.6 note 71 states that the C grammar provided by the specification defines the precedence of the C operators, and also states that the operator precedence resulting from the grammar closely follows the specification's section ordering

before dropping a table that appears to come more or less wholesale from cppreference.com (also included in other places - and to be fair there aren't really any options to "rephrase" something that's *that* objective).

**For someone who actually encountered a problem caused by operator precedence, that's not very helpful.**

Other attempts tend to bumble around the general topic without any clear organizational principle (and then copy and paste the same table, *without trying to explain its implications*). It turns out that **demonstrating CS concepts is hard** - to say nothing of actually *teaching* them.

Presumably, not very many people actually come in explicitly asking what the precedence rules are. In order to do that, one must first have the concept of precedence. To have *motivation* to do that, one must first *suspect that a problem* is related to precedence.

Instead, presumably the motivation *for creating* something like this, is to close questions *where the precedence issue is **not** realized by the OP*.

This is the point where lot of people will say "no, we can't do that, those are all just typo questions and sending them to a mega-answer is not being any more helpful, they have to dig through all the unrelated information about the precedence of *other* operators that *aren't* in their malfunctioning expression". But if you don't know that there's such a thing as operator precedence, or if you don't realize that it extends beyond grade-school math operations (see above), then it's useful to have your issue reframed in those terms.

So it would be better to have a question that addresses those kinds of problems - "why does this expression give that result?". It's a little hard to give such a question a title that doesn't "sound ridiculous" - the best I can come up with is "why aren't the code evaluated in order left to right?", which would trigger a lot of close reflexes - both for being trivial and for sounding opinion based, as if the plan were to argue against implementing an operator precedence scheme.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive feedback. I really didn't expect people to take issue with the simplicity of the `1 + 2 * 2` question and assumed that people would just look past it and see the question as an FAQ. I suppose it shows how useful it can be to get some feedback on Meta. I've incorporated your ideas into the FAQ question so that readers take a step back and think about *why* `1 + 2 * 2` is actually `5` in C++.

Comment: Past that, I still think that there is strong philosophical opposition to such an FAQ and there is nothing that I can do about it. I have gotten some extremely unconstructive feedback from some people which boils down to "This cannot be improved, it doesn't belong on Stack Overflow." Of course, such claims are opinionated and philosophical and can't be backed up by site policy or an appropriate close-vote. I agree with your take that dismissing such content may harm Stack Overflow in the long run.

Comment: My own attempts have received mixed results. You may also be interested in the [discussion around one of my worst-received attempts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418516). Granted, I don't use the same kind of FAQ format. I'm not a fan of the format generally, because people intuit that the Q in FAQ stands for "questions", plural. On the other hand, [sometimes it goes pretty well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72482298/). You can probably see for yourself many differences in the approach in those two cases.